# Equivalent condition to exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

> Let $M,M',M''$ $R$-modules, $R$ commutative ring with unit. $$0\xrightarrow{n_1} M'\xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M''\xrightarrow{n_2} 0$$ It is exact if and only if $M'\subseteq M$ submodule and $M'' \cong M/M'$.

The Proof of $\Rightarrow$ is clear. Indeed $\newcommand{\Im} {\operatorname{Im}} \Im(n_1) ={0}=\ker(f) \Rightarrow f$ is injective, then $f:M'\to M$ is an isomorphism and then $M'\cong \Im(f)$. So as we know from exactness that $ \Im(f) = \ker(g)$ we have $\ker(g)\cong M'$ and from the first theorem of isomorphism we have $\Im(g)\cong M/M'$. But $\ker(n_2) = M'' = \Im(g)$ and we have done.

What about the converse instead?

Comment: What is stopping e.g. $f = 0$ and $g = 0$ in the converse?

Comment: @ThomasShelby this would work, but wouldn't it be another sequence? Am I suppose to prove exactness with a specific $f,g$ or can I choose them on my own?

Comment: Okay, I see your point. In that case, Brian's comment provides a counterexample, right?

Comment: @ThomasShelby It seems so. Would the statement be true if $M''$ would be a submodule of $M$ as well?

Comment: @ele I don't think so.

Comment: It's true if you say $f(M') \subset M$ a submodule, $g \circ f = 0$ and $\text{im} g = M/\text{ker} g$.